# any example how to mass update with delayed job in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, delayed-job

trying to understand the delayed_job in Rails, I want to update all PIN which already expired in my gallery

```
class UpdatePinJob < ApplicationJob
 queue_as :default

 def perform(gallery)
   gallery.where('DATE(expired_pin) > ?', Date.today).update_all('pin = ?', 'new_pin_here')
 end

end
```

is that the correct way to use the job? and how do I call it then in my controller?
I hope my question makes sense, why I use a queue for this case because I was thinking how if my galleries have thousands, and I want to update all, that was I was thinking to use delayed_job might help for this to scale it :)
if something wrong on my question sorry, I am here trying to understanding

Comment: It looks like you set everything up correctly. All you need to do now is to enqueue the job. Check out [this Rails documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job).

Comment: is an above job I created correct ?? and can i use it every 2 weeks?

Comment: It is correct. You can use it every 2 weeks by using a cron job, or using the following: `UpdatePinJob.set(wait: 2.weeks).perform_later`.

Comment: will it run every 2 weeks? and should I put it on the controller model? :D just want to make sure @HarryLewis

Comment: For easy setup, I've created the gem [arask](https://github.com/Ebbe/arask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. I would advise to follow the instructions here: [ActiveJobsBasics](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html)

To call it in your controller you should do this:

```rb
# Enqueue a job to be performed as soon as the queuing system is free.
UpdatePinJob.perform_later(gallery)
# Enqueue a job to be performed 1 week from now.
UpdatePinJob.set(wait: 1.week).perform_later(gallery)
```

One important thing that you should aware of is about actually executing the job. According to ActiveJob:

> For enqueuing and executing jobs in production you need to set up a queuing backend, that is to say you need to decide for a 3rd-party queuing library that Rails should use. Rails itself only provides an in-process queuing system, which only keeps the jobs in RAM. If the process crashes or the machine is reset, then all outstanding jobs are lost with the default async backend. This may be fine for smaller apps or non-critical jobs, but most production apps will need to pick a persistent backend.

I would go with [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

Don't forget to do this:

```
# config/application.rb
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
    ...
  end
end
```

EDIT: If you are interested in how to schedule, that depends on what technology you are using.
If you are deploying with Heroku, you could use [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler). If you are deploying in Digital Ocean, you could use Cron Jobs.

Comment: thx for the good explanation, I was looking some background jobs 3rd party for few days this and I decide to use Delayed job, because Sidekep free not get all features and we just paid for it :D, but thx for suggestions,

Comment: No problem. If that answered your question, don't forget to mark as the correct answer.